# Is there a way to turn off “auto-maximize”?

Tags: 11.04, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to keep programs from launching maximized? 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40571/how-to-keep-programs-from-launching-maximized-11-04)

In 11.04 windows sometimes start maximized or jump to maximized when they get de-minimized. This behaviour starts to get annoying to me.

If I give a window a certain size—even if the window fills almost the entire screen—I want my OS to respect that and not make it’s own assumption. Is there a option to tell Ubuntu to maximize windows only when I press the maximize button?