# Prevent windows from opening fullscreen OR remember window size positon and workspace

Tags: windows, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to keep programs from launching maximized? 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40571/how-to-keep-programs-from-launching-maximized-11-04)

Is there any way to prevent windows from opening up fullscreen at login in Natty/11.04?

Or, to put it another way, is there a way to remember window size, workspace and position from one session to another?

Thanks