# How do I stop windows from maximizing when dragged into a corner?

Tags: 11.04

How do I stop windows from maximizing when dragging them into a corner? I'm guessing this is a compiz feature but I'm not finding it in ccsm. I've turned off unity so it shouldn't be that. I'm running Natty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep programs from launching maximized?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40571/how-to-keep-programs-from-launching-maximized)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the windows behaviour you can install and run Compiz Config Settings Manager [**ccsm**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ccsm) [image: Install ccsm].

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

> **Warning:** ccsm can lead to unwanted effects that may be hard to overcome and may leave you without a desktop (see also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/80589/3940) for more background information).

Choose *Grid* from *Window Management*:

[image]

and adapt the window's grid behaviour to your needs:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's the grid plugin in ccsm, deactivating it removes this feature. Or there are options to make it not maximise when dragging to the top but it will still fill one side of the screen when you drag it to that side.

Answer (score 1):

Just disabling the grid in the Compiz manager did not solve this for me.

I also had to use `gconf-editor` to uncheck:
/ -> desktop -> cinnamon -> windows -> edge_tiling.

After that, windows were no longer snapping to fullscreen.