# Prevent Unity from auto-maximizing

Tags: 11.04, unity, window-manager, resize

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a way to turn off “auto-maximize”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39489/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-auto-maximize)
>   [How to keep programs from launching maximized? 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40571/how-to-keep-programs-from-launching-maximized-11-04)

On a small netbook screen, it's useful to have windows maximized by default. However, on two separate machines with full-sized screens, Unity doesn't seem to realize that always opening browser windows maximized is just annoying.

How can I teach Unity the error of its ways? On a full-sized screen, I don't want Unity to auto-maximize any window, unless I happen to configure it to do so for a particular window (which is unlikely).

(By the way, I'm running Natty.)

Comment: Good catch. Wonder why I couldn't find the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can do to manage unity and its maximizing, although neither are 100% efficient.

Firstly use dconf-editor and switch the setting `Desktop > Unity > 'Form Factor'` to **Desktop**

Secondly you can use CCSM (compizconfig-settings-manager) and change the 'Place Windows > General > Placement Mode' to **Smart** - or which ever option works best for you.

Unfortunately I'm under the impression that this behavior is a feature, not a bug, to encourage us to use multiple desktops rather than clutter a single one.

Comment: Thanks, but no dice. Changing the form factor had no effect, and window placement was already set to smart. And multiple desktops in Unity are inconvenient. I used multiple desktops extensively pre-Natty, but now, I haven't found a good setup that works well with Unity. The default is hopelessly broken.

Comment: There is something else you can do, but I'm a little out of my depth beyond recommending you look into it. The program Devilspie allows you to take finer control over your windows, and their placement. Unfortunately I don't use it, but hopefully it'll set you on your way.