# How to stop maximizing windows in Unity 2d?

Tags: 11.10, unity-2d

Switch to another virtual desktop after unmaximizing a windows (Firefox, dconf-editor), and then return to the previous virtual desktop. Firefox becomes maximized again. How do I stop it???

I've tried setting `Desktop > Unity > 'Form Factor'` to desktop as suggested in
[Prevent Unity from auto-maximizing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45270/prevent-unity-from-auto-maximizing)

I've also tried stuff from [How to keep programs from launching maximized?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40571/how-to-keep-programs-from-launching-maximized), in particular:
`gconftool -s /apps/metacity/general/auto_maximize_windows -t bool false`

None of that works.

Please read the question before marking it as a duplicate. 
Please don't suggest CCSM, this is Unity2d.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Can you verify that the gconftool command worked? Log out, log in again, run `gconftool -g /apps/metacity/general/auto_maximize_windows` (or use `gconf-editor` if you prefer a GUI).

Comment: I was using Oneiric at the time, and actually had that info in the original title, but it was edited out by someone. Obviously, I've used gconf-editor and logged out/in.

Comment: Have you confirmed the setting was 'false' after you've logged back in? Just want to make sure that's working right. Also, you could try the same with a new user to confirm that it's not some issue with your user's configuration.

Comment: If I had not confirmed the settings, I would not be posting the question. The installation was a fresh one with no original user settings changed. Unity2d maximizes windows by design, not because of something the user did. Do you have a verified solution that works? If not, can you try and test them.

Comment: No, I cannot reproduce your issue. If I set 'auto_maximize_windows' to 'false', the window sizes stay untouched. :-/

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the problem described and setting `/apps/metacity/general/auto_maximize_windows` to `false` worked for me!  (11.10 [Oneiric] with Unity2D)

Answer (score 1):

After

```
gconftool -s /apps/metacity/general/auto_maximize_windows -t bool false
```

subsequently

```
gconftool -g /apps/metacity/general/auto_maximize_windows
```

returned

```
false
```

and the auto-maximize stopped occuring after log out-log in.
(Ubuntu 11.10 Unity2D)